# In-app purchase of consumable with quantity in windows store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to do an in-app purchase of a consumable per quantity in a windows store or windows phone 8 app? For ex: If the consumable is of type *10 gold coins*, can I initiate a in-app purchase of **2** *10 gold coins* or **5** *10 gold coins*?

Comment: This would be a good suggestion for improving the API. You can enter it at wpdev.uservoice.com.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to specify a quantity along with the product Id for a purchase currently ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn532255%28v=win.10%29.aspx)).  To address this, most applications just offer the consumables in various quantities (1, 10, 25, 50, 100, etc.).

While you may be able to create a lop that purchases and verifies each quantity, I'd suggest the more reliable would be to just make a single purchase of a larger predefined quantity.

Answer (score 0):

you are need to perform in app purchase shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206950(v=vs.105).aspx) and you can implement one purchase at a time.